# how to know tables name in the connected database in c#

Tags: c#

i have database which is already created from sql and i make connection on it is there is any way by which i can know the names of the tables in this database from c# as i know the tables in it but i won't to display tables names using code and programming and c#

Answer (score 1):

You could read schema and metadata information with ADO.NET. Here's an [example](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/schema-and-metadata-retrieval-using-ado.net/).

Comment: thanks very much 
i just have one more question how could i know the relations between a specific table and the other tables in the database to update the values in the related tables and also through the code